# Why I am getting this screen when I checked the size of the uploaded file in this file upload function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

In the file upload function that I am working on it, one important issue is to check the size of the uploaded file. If it is larger than the default size I should get an error message. However, I am getting this screen and I don't know why. Also, I tried to debug the code but debugging did not work at all. It did not go though any line of code and I don't know why

[image]

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try 
        {
            string[] validTypes = { "bmp", "gif"};
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            int size = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
            int limit = 84304;

            if (size < limit) 
            {
                .....................................                      
            }
            else 
            {
                Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                Label2.Text = "file is heavy";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text = "The file could not be uploaded." + ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should this `string path = @"~\Images\"` actually be `string path = @"~/Images/"` also in the `Server.MapPath(` change `"\\"` to `"/"`

Comment: I don't think this is the reason, because the function is working well except for a file with a size larger than the default size.

Comment: There is a setting in the config where you can set the `maxRequestength` I don't know how I missed reading that part initially ..sorry been coding all day my apologizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting that error message because the file you chose is larger than 4Mb, which is the default . If you want to increase the size of the files you want to upload you need to change it in web.config.

inside system.web tag add a line like this:

> `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="512000" />`

where 600 is the number of seconds and 512000 is the max size of the file in Kb

Comment: In case that I want to go with 4Mb, which should I do to show a proper error message than this screen?

Comment: If you look at my code, you will see that I am putting an error message in the Label, but I don't know why it doesn't work and getting this screen.

Comment: @androidFanBoy as i said: you get that error because of size of the file that you try to upload. If you want to limit the file to 4mb than set the maxRequestLength to a large number and then do exactly what yo u do now...

Comment: instead of having the `Label2.Tex` display the message why not use the `Response.Write()` to display it or use `javascript, or ClientScriptManager` to do an `Alert` Message..?